# how to solve http 500 error after installation of extension in magento?

Tags: magento-1.9, extensions, frontend, http-error-500

working on magento 1.9 website.

i am trying to develop a website, but after installing a extension am getting http 500 error can anyone please guide how to i resolve the same ?

is it a extension conflict or due to any else issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1)Delete the folder `var/cache/*`. You must give rights to the folder project.

2) In the index.php file, uncomment the line `#ini_set ('display_errors', 1);` . You will see a more accurate error than **500**.

Answer (score 0):

1)You need to clear the catch and enable display errors on.
2)Do check to disable third party module so without third party module your magento working or not ?

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```